# Windows GUI - Find out what has been clicked on the screen

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface

I'm using Eclipse on Windows 7, JNI with C.

I can't find a way to detect what has been clicked on the screen, eg: "Save File" on Microsoft Word, or the back navigation button on my browser; I don't know where to find a good tutorial, or a way to find it out.

Would someone please tell me what should I study to achieve this?

**[EDIT]**: until today, I achieved to get the title of the active window by:

```
    // In which window it has been typed/clicked something?
    void whichWindow(void) {
        HWND foreground = GetForegroundWindow();
        char window_title[256];
        if(foreground) {
            GetWindowText(foreground, window_title, 256);
            printf("active window title: %s\n", window_title);
        }
    }
```

I'll let you know when I'll be able to retrieve the window's elements clicked.

Comment: Sounds like this will be unsolvable; after all, you would have to ask the application itself since they might use their very own mechanism of drawing controls and the like.

Comment: Shouldn't I study the Windows API concerning the graphic, especially the windows management?
After all, when I click on something, the operative system (somehow) "realizes" something has been clicked...where does it get this "ack"?

Comment: You could register a [mouse hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C).

Comment: The operaring system uses a so called message pump which takes care of what is going on with hardware events like mouseclicks. It then passes the click interrupt to the executing program's CallBack. The callback us exactly what it sounds like. The message handler of each windows application, where then one can react to whatever message came in. Callback, because it more or less gets calles not by the program it is part of but by the os.

Comment: @icbytes: The OS does **not** use a message pump. GUI applications generally implement one or more message loops, that retrieve messages from the message queue and dispatch them to the respective target window procedures. The OS maintains a hardware input queue, where the hardware device driver stack enqueues events. The OS' raw input thread picks them up from there, passes them to hooks, updates input state, and finally places them in the appropriate application's input queue. The window procedure is called as a result of the application - **not** the OS - calling `DispatchMessage`.

Comment: Thx for the details. Sorry for my bad terminology. All together:agreed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several programs on the web which do this. IIRC winspy is one of them. It achieves this via setting a global mousehook which returns the programname of the clicked window.
How to absract this in JNI? Do not know, but this is the link, you asked for:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037/Hooks-and-DLLs

Comment: Seems to me this should rather be a comment than an answer.

Comment: Sounds like the Androidian `BroadcastReceiver`: I hope it's not written in C++, I'd prefer to keep all my code in C.
If this will be helpful, I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: @elmazzun: The Windows API does not know C++. It's C all the way through. However, a mouse hook will not give you the information you are looking for. It can monitor events like *"Left mouse button was pressed at location -807,201"*. It will not tell you *"This causes the 'File Save' command of 'Microsoft Word' to be invoked"*. If you need this information you should probably look into [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) instead. And even then it's a lot of tedious work.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @IInspectable 
Tedious or not, you guys just tell me what tools I need to achieve this :)