# Windows - What can we deduce from a mouse click on something "clickable"?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, user-interface

As the title suggests, I'm asking what can I find out by a click on the screen.

More precisely, can the click on an precise element (which can be the `+` symbol for opening a new tab on a generic browser, or the `File` and then `Save as...` elements on an Open Office document) be detected and return some kind of string of what has been clicked?

By working with Win32 API I am able to detect if the left button of the mouse has been clicked:

```
for(character=1; character<=222; character++) {
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(character) == -32767) {
        ...
        switch(character) {
            case VK_LBUTTON: ...; break;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

and when the click is detected, I know where it has been clicked (or, at least, the name of the window where the click happened):

```
    void whichWindow(FILE *f) {
        HWND foreground = GetForegroundWindow();
        char window_title[256];
        if(foreground) {
            GetWindowText(foreground, window_title, 256);
            fputs(window_title, f);
            getMenuFromWindow(f, foreground);
        }
        else fputs("Problem retrieving window's title name", f);
    }
```

Yet, I don't know *what* has been clicked.

You'll have figured out that getting mouse click's coordinates is useless to me, unless I know the coordinates of everything which can be clickable on the screen.

I checked WindowsUI Automation, but most of it is in C# and, for my porpouses, I'd prefer to stay in C.

Lot of people told me to use one of the programs in the web, but as I said, I'd prefer to use only C, without including some extern library.

So: is there a way to find out if I clicked "New File" on some text editor, or "Play" on VLC, just by using Windows API?

Comment: You can use UI automation from C. Not that it would be a lot of fun. You'd need to do something like that anyway because Win32 has no idea, in general, what happens when you click. Only the apps know that.

Comment: The MSDN documentation is poorly written; can't find a decent example.

Sigh, so I won't get it out with a single file.c?

Comment: The MSDN documentation is just fine. You just need to know how to consume COM from C. A saner approach would be to use C++.

Comment: Can you deepen the "how to consume COM from C" sentence?

Comment: The problem you are facing is that on the level of WinAPI there is no UI objects. On this level all you have is just pixels. If you want to stay on this level it is on your shoulder to translate pixel coordinates into whatever object structure you have in your program

Comment: I thought that HWND, HMENU and others type of data were UI objects abstracted enough to work with; so, do I have to study this COM and UI Automation?

Comment: What if the GUI doesn't use windowed controls

Comment: If you experts say so, give me your blessing if you think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will help me in my quest.

Comment: As for consuming COM from C just do a search

Comment: This is exactly what the accessibility interfaces are for. If UI Automation is too complicated, you can use the old IAccessible interface instead.

Comment: Why do you assume that [asking the exact same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25339727/1889329) again will yield different answers? You were told to use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) already, and the answer hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can get hold of the handle, text and the classname of a (child) window under the mouse cursor with logic like:

```
HWND hWndF = GetForegroundWindow();
if (hWndF != NULL)
{   HWND hWndC;
    TCHAR szClassName[64], szWindowText[256];
    POINT pt;

    GetClassName(hWndF, szClassName, _countof(szClassName));    // main window
    GetWindowText(hWndF, szWindowText, _countof(szWindowText)); // main window

    GetCursorPos(&pt);          // in screen coordinates
    ScreenToClient(hWndF, &pt); // in client coordinates of main window
    hWndC = ChildWindowFromPointEx(hWndF, pt, CWP_ALL);
    if (hWndC != NULL && hWndC != hWndF)
    {   GetClassName(hWndC, szClassName, _countof(szClassName));    // child window
        GetWindowText(hWndC, szWindowText, _countof(szWindowText)); // child window
    }
}
```

Comment: `szWindowText` of the child window is always null...what if I get a HMENU handler and get the selected item of the menu?

Comment: you can use the above logic only to get information on child `WINDOW`s, HMENU is not a Window -- also be aware that some of the fancy toolbars in some applitions are not real windows in the API sense -- it looks like UI Automation is the only way to go...

Comment: What about `PeekMessage`? I could use it to catch the `WM_COMMAND` and analize it

Comment: you cannot use PeekMessage for messages belonging to another thread

Comment: ...what if I `hook` the messages?

Comment: sorry, I have no knowledge on hooking messages

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Windows expert, but reading the docs, a way it can work:

```
TCHAR lpClassName[64];
HWND foreground = GetForegroundWindow();
int ret;

ret = GetClassName(foreground, (LPTSTR)lpClassName, 64);
if(ret == 0) {
    // GetLastError and friends...
}
```

This way you should get the name of the class of the window that was previously registered with  `RegisterClass()` or `RegisterClassEx()`. That string should tell you more about the nature of the window.

**Note:** Since I don't know/get Win32 data types, above usage of the char array and/or the length parameter of `GetClassName()` may be wrong.

You may get more information from the class with `GetClassInfo()`. For general reference, read [About Window Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: Until now, I managed to get the number of elements of the menu bar associated to a window...If I could get which element of the menu bar has been clicked, that would be an improvement.

Comment: Did you try to get the child windows? Maybe you clicked slightly outside the label. Anyway, as long as menu is done with labels, you should find these labels ("static" control) as windows on the screen (except if the menu was closed again). If nothing helps, you may use `GetMenu()` and friends to `GetMenuItemRect()` which will tell you the menu position on the screen which you should be able to match your mouse click. But again, I don't think this is necessary...

Comment: A window class tells you **nothing** about its *nature*. It is a character string, arbitrarily chosen by the caller of `RegisterClass[Ex]` (i.e. the facility that provides a particular window class). With the exception of `#32770` (dialog) and standard control classes that you could special case, there's nothing you can do with this information. You cannot, for example, query for accepted control-specific messages.